# Invalid Siri Support - Localized description for custom intent

Tags: shortcut, sirikit, ios12

I have uploaded a binary to iTunes Connect but I have receiving this email:

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "xxx". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

Invalid Siri Support - Localized description for custom intent: "xxxxxx" not found for locale: zh_CN

Invalid Siri Support - Localized title for custom intent: "xxxxxx" not found for locale: zh_CN

I have added localized title and description in Intents.strings for the "zh_CN" language but nothing worked.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F32dC.png)

Could someone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The two answers are useless because creator said that he does use localization. As do I, but that's not problem Apple has with our code.

Comment: @hoshy Have you ever got this problem resolved?

Comment: @Neal.Marlin if you follow the steps below from JMiguel those will create the localization files that are needed.

Answer (score 26):

Remember to enter your description

[image]

Comment: This was the solution in my case. Even if you have localization enabled, if the description is blank (and so has no translation), this seems to trigger the warning message.

Comment: Where do you write the localized description? Localizable.strings?

Answer (score 17):

- On your .intentdefinition file select the intent.

[image: intent selection]

- On the right bar of the Xcode window there should be a Localize button on the Localization section. Press it.

[image: localization button]

- Select Base (or the default project language you are using) on the presented dialog.

[image: language dialog]

- Add a check to all the localization you need to use, on the localization section.

[image: localization files]

- Edit the new localization files accordingly...

Comment: As creator said, the file is localized. As is mine (having the same issue).

Comment: Following these steps helped created the localization files that were needed.

Comment: This is the solution. Careful to Select Base first. Then add the others.  Otherwise it corrupts the project.

Comment: In my case there is no "localize" button. I have no possibility to add the strings. What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

### I'm having the same problem [Note: Take code backup]. Select the Localization file to uncheck

[image]]

[image]

### Remove that and clear trash. Now check to mark it on Localization file which unchecks previous

.

[image]